# jQuery Validate require_from_group - How to implement two groups, with only one being ultimately required?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form where a user is supposed to be able to search for data by entering EITHER an address (in individual street, city, country, state fields) OR one of 4 particular codes the company uses internally to describe the data.

I've assigned the address fields one class name (per the Validate rule) and the special codes fields another.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to NOT require one or the other of those two groups if the *other* group's fields are all filled in. IE - if the user completes all the address fields, he should not be required to fill in any of the special codes text boxes and conversely if the user populates one of the special codes, she should not be required to fill in address values.

I'm using C# and jQuery Validate 1.11 - with a fix to the original require_from_group function which resolved a reported issue of skipping all validations after an initial group validation (or something like that).

Here is the code on the form showing the fields in question:

```
<div class="evenFormPaddedWide mb" style="max-width:575px;">
    <label>Address</label><br />
    <div class="pDiv">
        <div class="elementDiv">
            <label>Street</label><br />
            <asp:TextBox id="txtAddress" runat="server" Width="250px" MaxLength="65" CssClass="GroupAddress"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="elementDiv">
            <label>City</label><br />
            <asp:TextBox id="txtCity" runat="server" Width="120px" MaxLength="60" CssClass="GroupAddress"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pDiv">
        <div class="elementDiv">
            <label>Country</label><br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountries" CssClass="GroupAddress" runat="server" DataValueField="CountryCode" DataTextField="CountryName" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountries_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div class="elementDiv">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlStates" runat="server">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCountries" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"/>
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                        <label>State</label><br />
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStates" CssClass="GroupAddress" runat="server" DataValueField="GeopoliticalCode" DataTextField="GeopoliticalName"></asp:DropDownList>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="formLine"></div>
    <div class="pDiv">
        <div class="elementDiv">
            <label>CLLI Code</label><br />
            <asp:TextBox id="txtClliCode" runat="server" Width="100px" MaxLength="11" CssClass="GroupIDCodes"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="elementDiv">
            <label>Site Code</label><br />
            <asp:TextBox id="txtSiteCode" runat="server" Width="100px" MaxLength="8" CssClass="GroupIDCodes"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="elementDiv">
            <label>F&E Location Code</label><br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocationCode" runat="server" MaxLength="10" Columns="12" CssClass="GroupIDCodes"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="elementDiv">
            <label>MUX Code</label><br />
            <asp:TextBox id="txtMuxCode" runat="server" Width="50px" MaxLength="3" CssClass="GroupIDCodes"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="formLine"></div>
    <div class="fr">
        <asp:Button id="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Search"     onclick="btnSubmit_Click"></asp:Button>
        <asp:Button id="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" onclick="btnClear_Click" CausesValidation="False" CssClass="cancel"></asp:Button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is how I'm utilizing the require_from_group2 function:

```
$(function () {
    jQuery.validator.messages.required = "";

    $('#userInputForm').validate({
        rules: {
            txtAddress: {
                minlength: 6,
                require_from_group2: [4, ".GroupAddress"]
            },
            txtCity: { require_from_group2: [4, ".GroupAddress"] },
            ddlCountries: { require_from_group2: [4, ".GroupAddress"] },
            ddlStates: { require_from_group2: [4, ".GroupAddress"] },
            txtClliCode: { require_from_group2: [1, ".GroupIDCodes"] },
            txtSiteCode: { require_from_group2: [1, ".GroupIDCodes"] },
            txtLocationCode: { require_from_group2: [1, ".GroupIDCodes"] },
            txtMuxCode: { require_from_group2: [1, ".GroupIDCodes"] }
        },
        //End rules
        groups: {
            Address: "txtAddress txtCity ddlCountries ddlStates",
            OtherCodes: "txtClliCode txtSiteCode txtLocationCode txtMuxCode"
        },
        //End groups
        messages: {
            txtAddress: { minlength: "Street requires at least 6 characters", require_from_group2: "All address fields are required when searching by address" },
            txtCity: { require_from_group2: "All address fields are required when searching by address" },
            ddlCountries: { require_from_group2: "All address fields are required when searching by address" },
            ddlStates: { require_from_group2: "All address fields are required when searching by address" },
            txtClliCode: { require_from_group2: "At least one of the bottom 4 code fields must be provided if not searching by address" },
            txtSiteCode: { require_from_group2: "At least one of the bottom 4 code fields must be provided if not searching by address" },
            txtLocationCode: { require_from_group2: "At least one of the bottom 4 code fields must be provided if not searching by address" },
            txtMuxCode: { require_from_group2: "At least one of the bottom 4 code fields must be provided if not searching by address" }
        },
        //End messages
        errorLabelContainer: "#errorMessageDetailContainerLeft"
    });
});
```

And just in case, here's the fixed require_from_group:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("require_from_group2", function (value, element, options) {
    var validator = this;
    var minRequired = options[0];
    var selector = options[1];
    var validOrNot = jQuery(selector, element.form).filter(function () {
        return validator.elementValue(this);
    }).length >= minRequired;

    // remove all events in namespace upload

    jQuery(selector, element.form).off('.require_from_group2');

    if (this.settings.onkeyup) {
        jQuery(selector, element.form).on({
            'keyup.require_from_group2': function (e) {
                jQuery(selector, element.form).valid();
            }
        });
    }
    if (this.settings.onfocusin) {
        jQuery(selector, element.form).on({
            'focusin.require_from_group2': function (e) {
                jQuery(selector, element.form).valid();
            }
        });
    }
    if (this.settings.click) {
        jQuery(selector, element.form).on({
            'click.require_from_group2': function (e) {
                jQuery(selector, element.form).valid();
            }
        });
    }
    if (this.settings.focusout) {
        jQuery(selector, element.form).on({
            'focusout.require_from_group2': function (e) {
                jQuery(selector, element.form).valid();
            }
        });
    }

    return validOrNot;
}, jQuery.format("Please fill at least {0} of these fields."));
```

Any help is certainly appreciated!

Comment: FYI, version 1.11.1 resolved all previously reported issues.

Comment: Thanks Sparky, I'll check it out immediately. I'm still a little skeptical though as to whether how to do what I'm asking is clear. I don't know that I'm running into an _issue_ per se, it may be more me just not knowing how to work with multiple groups on a page and ultimately making only one of those groups required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is overly complex and I'm not sure `require_from_group` is the appropriate method for what you're trying to do.  It's only supposed to make any specific number of elements *FROM* a group of elements required.  In other words, if you have six items in your group and you specify "2" as the argument, then this method/rule will only be satisfied if ***any*** two *fields* from your group of six are filled out.

In your case, you want everything within one group filled out as opposed to everything in another group filled out, which is something else entirely.

With jQuery Validate, you cannot switch validation on/off dynamically.  Once defined and initialized, it stays "on".  However, you can use [the `.rules()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) to dynamically over-write, add or remove any rule on any field(s) at any time.

I would make the user physically select one group or the other by clicking a radio or checkbox.  This will also reduce confusion about what the user is expected to fill in.  However, if you don't like that idea, you could instead use the `blur`, `change`, or another event on any field to trigger similar "rule altering" code.

Then based on the event, you can modify your rules accordingly.

```
$('input[name="radio"]:radio').on('change', function () {  // on selection event
    if ($('#one').is(':checked')) {            // if first radio is selected
        $('.inputGroup1 ').each(function () {  // add rules to first group
            $(this).rules('add', {
                required: true
            });
        });
        $('.inputGroup2').each(function () {  // remove rules from second group
            $(this).rules('remove');
        });
    } else {                                  // if second radio is selected
        $('.inputGroup2').each(function () {  // add rules to second group
            $(this).rules('add', {
                required: true
            });
        });
        $('.inputGroup1').each(function () {  // remove rules from first group
            $(this).rules('remove');
        });
    };
});
```

**Proof of Concept:  http://jsfiddle.net/tF8Wp/**

Comment: Thanks again. A small correction to what you've inferred - in the second group, the client states only one of those fields should be required, not all. I don't know why that's complex - either search by an address (in which case provide all the components) or search by a particular code.

I do agree that perhaps using require_from_group for both of the sets of fields might ought to be rethought. A radio button to choose one or the other won't fly with the client. I'll go back to the drawing board a little. Thank you very much for the suggestion about removing rules!

Comment: @Emmie, I meant that your code seems to be overly complex, not your concept.  As explained in my answer, you don't have to use a radio button:  _"However, if you don't like that idea, you could instead use the `blur`, `change`, or another event on any field to trigger similar 'rule altering' code."_  In other words, if one field is filled out in a group, then all fields in only that group become required.  Same concept; different selector and event.  ~ Please "accept" my answer if you found it helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: Understood. I like it. It points me in a better direction, thanks.